# Related playlists are not listed when requesting playlists by channelId

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Let's do a request to get a channel (e.g `forUsername=physicswoman`) and its related playlists exposed in the `contentDetails` object:

[image: Get Physics Girl channel]

We have an `uploads` playlist with id `UU7DdEm33SyaTDtWYGO2CwdA`.

Now let's request this channel's playlists:

[image: Get channel's playlists 1/2]

[image: Get channel's playlists 2/2]

Where is the `uploads` playlist?

The funny part is that if I do a request to get the `uploads` playlist with its id, it's there and the corresponding channelId is the one of the channel

[image: Get playlist from its id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the expected behavior from the YouTube Data API since these playlists are not necessarily containing user's videos.

It's also interesting to notice how Google decided to manage this kind of architecture problem.

Comment: As you have noted, this is normal behaviour. Reason is that the user uploads was moved to the playlist category in api v3. So it is now technically a playlist, but not an actual playlist. As in it was not put together to be one. That is why it starts with 'UU' rather than 'PL' . But it is accessible through the playlist parameters.